# Spring Rest 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, spring, rest

I m getting 400 Bad Request but i have no idea why. It seems everything fine to me. I would appreciate some ideas..

```
@Component
public class TicketIdentifierRestClient implements TicketIdentifierService{
@Autowired
private RestClient restClient;

@Override
public List<TicketIdentifierDto> createTicketIdentifier(List<TicketIdentifierDto> list)
        throws ServiceException {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = this.restClient.getRestTemplate();
    String url = this.restClient.createServiceUrl("/ticketIdentifier/");

    HttpHeaders headers = this.restClient.getHttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    ;
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
    List<TicketIdentifierDto> tickets = null;
//  System.out.println("necati"+list.get(0).toString());
    try {
        ParameterizedTypeReference<List<TicketIdentifierDto>> ref = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<TicketIdentifierDto>>() {};
        ResponseEntity<List<TicketIdentifierDto>> response = restTemplate.exchange(URI.create(url), HttpMethod.POST, entity,ref);
        tickets = response.getBody();
        return tickets;

    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ServiceException("Could not retrieve tickets: " + e.getMessage(), e);

    }
}
```

and the server side i m just trying to get the list and print it out here

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/ticketIdentifier")
public class TicketIdentifierController {
private  final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TicketController.class);
@Autowired
private TicketIdentifierService tiService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<TicketIdentifierDto> getTickets(@RequestBody List<TicketIdentifierDto> list) throws ServiceException {
    System.out.println("did i get it ?"+list.get(0).toString());
    //return EntityToDto.convertTicketIdentifiers(tiService.create(list));
    return list;
}
}
```

Comment: Set the spring logging to trace and check out what it says.

Comment: What happens if you add a breakpoint in your code? Does it get hit?

Comment: sorry what is breakpoint ?

Answer (score 0):

Server side seems ok.

I write this few line of code:
I write a simple class test

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Test {

    String text;

    int number;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public Test(String text, int number) {
        super();
        this.text = text;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Test() {
        super();
    }

}
```

And a simple client

```
public class Application {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List<Test> list = new ArrayList<Test>();
    Test request = new Test();
    request.number = 1;
    request.text = "txt1";

    Test request2 = new Test();
    request2.number = 2;
    request2.text = "txt2";

    list.add(request);
    list.add(request2);

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    ResponseEntity<ArrayList> test = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/postevent", list, ArrayList.class);
    System.out.println(test.getBody().toString());//show json
    for(int i =0; i<list.size();i++){
        System.out.println("number "+list.get(i).number +" text "+ list.get(i).text);
    }

}
```

}

Server side:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/postevent")
public class PostEvent {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes= "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody List<Test> getTickets(@RequestBody List<Test> list) {
        for(int i =0; i<list.size();i++){
            System.out.println("number "+list.get(i).number +" text "+ list.get(i).text);
        }
        return list;
    }


}
```

Comment: Try to add some detail about error. You can also try to use advanced rest client on chrome to test your service and post some additional detail.

Comment: i could see that the error happens because i m trying to send and arraylist in a Dto..when i do it other way around and not send the list it works..